# Execute Airflow DAG instances (tasks) on a list of specific dates

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to manage a couple of future releases using Apache airflow. 
All of these releases are known way in advance and I need to make sure some data pushing won't be forgotten.

The problem is that those future release do not follow a simple periodic schedule that could be handled with a classic cron like `0 1 23 * *` or something like `@monthly`.

It's rather `2019-08-24`, `2019-09-30` , `2019-10-20` ...

Is there another way but to create a seperate `mydag.py` file for all of those future releases? What is the standard / recommended way to do this? Am I thinking about this the wrong way (I wonder because the documentation and tutorials rather focus on the regular, periodic thing)?

Comment: Which solution did you use? Did you choose any of the answers?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two simple ways of doing this

1. Create 3-4 top-level DAGs, each having specific `start_date` = 2019-08-24, 2019-09-30... and [`schedule_interval='@once'`](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs)
2. Create a single top-level DAG having `schedule_interval=None` (`start_date` can be anything). Then create a "triggering-dag", that employs [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.html) to [conditionally trigger](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py#L45) your actual workflow on specific dates

Clearly the method 2 above is better

Comment: I guess 1 is what I am trying to avoid, as I have manage several groups of irregular monthly release and I don't want to have 50-60 dags because of this. 2 sounds interesting but I haven't use those yet. What's important is that exact execution time works.

Answer (score 3):

You could give your DAG a `@daily` schedule, then start it with a [ShortCircuitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator) task that checks to see if the execution date matches a release date. If it is, you pass the check and the DAG runs. Otherwise, it skips the entire DAG and no release happens. See an example of this operator being used in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/example_dags/example_short_circuit_operator.py.

I imagine it'd look something like this:

```
RELEASE_DATES = ['2019-08-24', '2019-09-30', '2019-10-20']

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval='@daily', 
    default_args=default_args,
)

def check_release_date(**context):
    # pass if it's a release day
    return context['ds'] in RELEASE_DATES

skip_if_not_release_date = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='skip_if_not_release_date',
    python_callable=check_release_date,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True,
)
```

If release dates can change, then you might want to make this a little more dynamic with variables to make updates easy.

```
def check_release_date(**context):
    release_dates = Variable.get('release_dates', deserialize_json=True)
    return context['ds'] in RELEASE_DATES
```

Also if for whatever reason you need to override your hardcoded list of release dates, you can mark this task as success to force the DAG to run.

Comment: Also thought of this, but it felt like a sort of workaround / hack. So maybe a little confirmation through more experienced user and other examples is what I need here. It would allow me to get those release dates from airflow variables...